# Using nodejs app inside Flask application in the static folder fails with relative imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, flask

I need a nodejs module inside my Flask website. I have `npm install` the module in the `static` subfolder `hh/hh/hh.js` of Flask now I am rendering the template with the page where I need the module using `url_for` in the appropriate `script tag`:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='hh/hh/hh.js')}}"></script>
```

It seems it is able to load the script and the associated files however I have a 404 because some javascript file inside the module is trying to access a file in a subfolder `hh/lib/filetoaccess.json`.

I've also tried to use a `npm run eject` and modify the conig.json to rebuild the whole package inside the static folder but still some relative path are missing.

Is there any way I can force the module to use relative imports? Or a better way to use a Nodejs app in the front-end of my Flask app?

> The module is working properly when I use `npm start` which is
> launching a Nodejs server but launched using the test Flask server
> doesn't work.